# Change tab order inside ToolStripMenu

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

When the ToolStrip control is focused the first ToolStripItem is focused too.
I need to set the focus to the second item, but there is no TabIndex property in ToolStripItems.
I've tried to select the item manually when the ToolStrip gets the focus, but there is no Focus method either.
Actually, we use a inherited control, so I can create custom properties/methods, if it's needed.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ToolStrip is doing *something* when it fires the Enter event, so just setting the focus on a ToolStripItem won't work unless you focus *after* the enter event code has completed.  The BeginInvoke method is a way to run code after the event has finished:

```
Private Sub ToolStrip1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStrip1.Enter
  Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub()
                              ToolStrip1.Items(1).Select()
                            End Sub))
End Sub
```

Comment: @SubazSarma It doesn't on my machine.

Comment: @SubazSarma : Mine neither.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked!
I've tried to remove the BeginInvoke and it doesn't work, could you explain me why this is needed?

Comment: @JotaSantana It seems like the ToolStrip is overriding some behavior during that Enter event.  BeginInvoke is a way to run some code "after" a method is completed. I guessed BeginInvoke might work and it did.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do a research about that topic, I've never used this before.

Comment: @LarsTech : You should add that to the answer for future readers to see.